# apache Nifi : updateAttribute processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm trying to update an attribute (for example let's call it myAttribute) in order to replace all " by \"
for example :

- {"field1":1,"field2":{"field21":21,"field22":"22"}} will become
- {\"field1\":1,\"field2\":{\"field21\":21,\"field22\":\"22\"}}

for that purpose I'm using the updateAttribute procesor with the replaceAll function
for example :

- property : myAttribute
- Value : ${log.message:replaceAll('"','\"')}

the result is the same (\ is used as escape sequence prefix)
I tried to use also two \\ but the result is the same.

Someone can help me ?

Comment: FYI there is a function for escaping json in expression language https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#escapejson

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems like there's a bug in the `replaceAll` function of the expression language..

But anyways, it seems like you're trying to escape your Json which `escapeJson` would solve..

So instead, just use `${log.message:escapeJson()}`

Answer (score 0):

Probably `escapeJson` is the best option but if you need to do it with `replaceAll`, try this:

- `${log.message:replaceAll("\"","\\\\\"")}`

or

- `${log.message:replaceAll('"','\\\\"')}`

I've tested with NiFi 1.9.0 and it works.